# jQuery incrementation param passing weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me describe my scenario before I say my question:

Let counter be defined already as a number starting from 0.

I have 2 a tags: let them be a1 and a2

I first dynamically added a1 into my html and then used this:

```
jQuery("a.adder").click(function(){adder(this, counter)});
```

then I did `counter++`

then I dynamically added a2 into my html and then used this again on **both** my a tags

```
jQuery("a.adder").click(function(){adder(this, counter)});
```

then I did `counter++`

also, in my `adder(param1, param2)` , all I do is `alert(counter)`

Okay here's my question: After doing all that, when I clicked on a1 which has 2 handlers, the alert output is 2 (it alerts twice for each handler) and for a2, the alert is also 2  when clicked. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it returns 2 for both is that your anonymous functions are creating a closure over the counter variable. What this means is that those methods don't just have the current value of counter when you bind them, they have a **reference** to the variable.

Any changes in that variable later on will be reflected in the captured variable.

You can prevent this by creating a new variable for the second binding:

```
var counter = 0;
function adder(e, counter) {
    alert(counter);
}


jQuery("<a class='adder'>a1</a><br />')").appendTo("body");
jQuery("a.adder").click(function(){adder(this, counter)});
counter++;
var newCounter = counter;
jQuery("<a class='adder'>a2</a>')").appendTo("body");
jQuery("a.adder").click(function(){adder(this, c)});
counter++;
```

Here is created a new counter variable called newCounter which is capture by the second event handler.

Comment: Uhm, what does closure mean? I haven't heard of that term before

Comment: I would read the url that Matthijus posted for a good in depth look at closures. But in short, it is when you have variables in scope and you define a function this function will "close over" or capture those variables so that even if you pass that function around it will still have references to them.

Comment: ill look into the reference. So im guessing that it's because in javascript, even numbers are objects so when I passed counter into adder, the reference to the number was passed along too which is why this behavior occurred?

Comment: Not really. In programming languages the concept is sometimes referred to as L-value and R-value. L-values are the address in memory where objects/value are store. These are called L-values since they appear on the left side of = signs. R-Value on the other hand represent values of expressions. 
So when you created the closure it grabs the L-value of the variable which is just the location where the value lives but not the value.

Answer (score 0):

you made two click events, and your click events return the current value of 'counter'